# Unexpected behaviour in PHP Altorouter when passing parameters

Tags: php, arrays, php-closures, altorouter

**Setup**

I'm accessing this url: `<host>/render/z63034/RBLR/GLZB`.

My url pattern is as such: `/render/[a:title]/[a:bpFrom]/[a:bpTo]`.

My route gets added like so:

```
$router->map("GET", "/render/[a:title]/[a:bpFrom]/[a:bpTo]", function ($params) { include __DIR__ . "/views/render.php"; }, "render");
```

The call then looks like this:

```
call_user_func_array($match['target'], $match['params']);
```

In my `index.php`(where all requests are routed to) a `var_dump()` of `$match['params']` yields the expected:

```
array(3) {
  ["title"]=>
  string(6) "z63034"
  ["bpFrom"]=>
  string(4) "RBLR"
  ["bpTo"]=>
  string(4) "GLZB"
}
```

In my `render.php` (which is included) a `var_dump()` of `$params` yields the unexpected

```
string(6) "z63034"
```

**Question**

Why is only the first element in the array I'm passing to `call_user_func_array` actually passed (not as an array, but just as the value itself)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that `call_user_func_array`passes the `$params` as single parameters, with this I mean, that in your function definition, you have to declare as much parameters as your `$params` array has.

For example if you call this:

```
$params = array('Hello', 'World');
call_user_func_array(array($this,'test'), $params);
```

And your function definition looks like that

```
 function test($a){
        echo $a; 
        echo $b; 
        echo '<br>';
    }
```

you will only print 'Hello', so you have to declare your function like this

```
function test($a, $b){
        echo $a; 
        echo $b; 
        echo '<br>';
    }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I ended up using `call_user_func()` to just pass the array of parameters as an array.